# openGL Camera space vs NDC viewing direction

Tags: opengl

I am trying to understand open GL concepts . While reading this tutorial - http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut04%20Perspective%20Projection.html,
I came accross this statement :

This is because camera space and NDC space have different viewing directions. In camera space, the camera looks down the -Z axis; more negative Z values are farther away. In NDC space, the camera looks down the +Z axis; more positive Z values are farther away. The diagram flips the axis so that the viewing direction can remain the same between the two images (up is away).

I am confused as to why the viewing direction has to change . Could some one please help me understand this with an example ?

Comment: It does not ***have*** to change. clip-, NDC- and window-space all have a convention wherein positive Z points forward (and *that* is not something you can change), but you have full control over all of the coordinate spaces prior to clip-space in the programmable pipeline, so you can implement anything you want (the discussion in the arcsynthesis tutorial is a relict from fixed-function GL).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is mostly just a convention. OpenGL clip space (and NDC space and screen space) has always been defined as left-handed (with z pointing away into the screen) by the spec.

OpenGL eye space had been defined with camera at origin and looking at -z direction (so right-handed). However, this convention was just meaningful in the fixed-function pipeline, where together with the fixed function per vertex lighting which was carried out in eye space, the viewing direction did matter cases like when`GL_LOCAL_VIEWER` was disabled (as was the default).

The classic GL projection matrix typically converts the handedness, and the perspecitve division is done with a divisior of `-z_eye`, typically, so the last row of the projection matrix is typically (0, 0, -1, 0). The old `glFrustum()`, `glOrtho()`, and `gluPerspective()` actually supported that convention by using the `z_near` and `z_far` clipping distances *negated*, so that you had to specify positive values for clip planes to lie before the camera at `z<0`.

However, with modern GL, this convention is more or less meaningless. There is no fixed-function unit left which does work in eye space, so the eye space (and anything before that) is totally under the user's control. You can use anything you like here. The clip space and all the later spaces are still used by fixed function units (clipping, rasterization, ...), so there most be some convention to define the interface, and it is still a left-handed system.

Even in modern GL, the old right-handed eye space convention is still in use. The popular glm library for example reimplements the old GL matrix functions the same way.

There is really no reason to prefer one of the possible conventions over the other, but at some point, you have to choose and stick to one.